# How can I rotate an element to 180deg the back to 0deg using the same button in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, rotation

the code runs all the way over and over. I need the button to rotate to 180 then back again to 0deg then again to 180 incrementing and decrementing by 45deg

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ttt</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="memo" style="position: fixed;margin: 140px;">
    _____________
  </div>

  <button onclick="myfun()">Rotate</button>
  <script>
    function myfun() {
      var i = 0
      i += 45;
      document.getElementById("memo").style.transform += "rotate(" + i + "deg)";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please change the value of `i += 90`

Answer (score 0):

Rotating something by 180 degrees and than back to 0 is the same as rotating it towards 360 right?
Why would you need to rotate it back to 0 if you can just keep increasing by 180?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I needed the it specifically to rotate by 45deg back and forth but thanks Frank I got the correct answers above

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.
We start out with direction +
Whenever rotation reaches 180, change direction to -
Whenever rotation reaches 0, change direction back to +
We track the rotation in the i variable

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ttt</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="memo" style="position: fixed;margin: 140px;">
    _____________
  </div>

  <button onclick="myfun()">Rotate</button>
  <script>
    let i = 0;
    let direction = '+';

    function myfun() {
        if (i === 180) direction = '-';
        if (i === 0) direction = '+';
        if (i < 180 && direction === '+') {
          i += 45;
        } else {
          i -= 45;
        }
        console.log(i);
      document.getElementById("memo").style.transform += "rotate(" + direction + 45 + "deg)" ;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see where my mistake was I just could not figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @anelebango Happy to help! Mark my answer as the correct one in case any one else runs into a similar problem and finds this thread. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the rotation of element first, as variable, then you can change direction of rotation for example like this.

```js
if(currentrotation>=180)
    {
     rightrotation=false
    };
else if(currentrotation<=0)
    {
    rightrotation=true
    }

if(rightrotation)
   {
    i+=45;
   }
else
   {
   i-=45;
   }
```

To get current value of rotation you need to do some math functions. I have found this website that explains it [Get Rotation value of css](https://programmer.help/blogs/get-the-rotation-value-of-css-through-javascript.html)

**EDIT: @Frank Castle already posted better solution**